# How do i remove 'quotes' from strings that can contain single quotes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, escaping

I have params that is returning `4, 36, 'new tag', 52, 'Mcdonald\'s', 25` as a string.

I then split them by , and then i need to do some work on them.

First, I need to create a new tag based on that, but i need to somehow gsub (or something?) the outside quotes, but not the inner ones (if the tag contains it, like McDonald's above)

Second, I need to unescape the \ that the token input adds. I'm not sure how to do that second step so its the best security-wise

PS. I have validations on that model so I'm hoping that's good enough and i dont have to worry about some kind of SQL injection thing

Comment: May I ask, why is it that you need to unescape the input? If you try `puts 'Mcdonald\'s'` in irb then you should get "Mcdonald's".

Comment: I need to create a Tag.new(:name => token), but each token is split on the ,  .. so the string includes the escape

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm not quite seeing the problem. Have you tried it and it gave some sort of error? It's just that if it's escaped then Ruby will deal with it, it's not something you should need to think about. For example `"Mcdonald\'s".to_sym` gives `:"Mcdonald's"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params.split(/,\s+/).map{|s| s.start_with?("'") && s.end_with?("'") ? s[1..-2] : s }
```

That should clear up the first part about quotes.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how i unescape it?

Comment: see my question above, but unless you have a specific reason to unescape it then don't - it'll come out the other side fine.

Comment: its not, they're being saved as "McDonald\'s"

Comment: try appending to the above `.map{|s| s.gsub %r{\\},"" }` as long as you are sure you won't need any backslashes at all. If you're using an ORM's model to make the saves to the database then it should take care of SQL injection, no need to worry about that.